# Order of tensor product in quantum mechanics? Why it doesn't matter?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, quantum-information, many-body

I am looking for a somewhat "official"/accepted proof or rationale on why the order of tensor product doesn't matter in physics but matters in mathematics.

In every book of quantum theory (for ex cohen tannoudji page 154 volume1) it says or suggests that for a quantum composite system the order of the taken tensor product of the subsystems doesn't matter. Meaning that we can take either: $$|\psi\rangle\otimes |\chi\rangle$$ or $$|\chi\rangle\otimes |\psi\rangle$$ and it wouldn't really matter.

However mathematically the two states are obviously different and they belong to two different distinguishable Hilbert spaces really.

Are there any discussions/papers about this question? I don't get the apparent triviality of it.

Comment: Mathematically, the order doesn't matter. To be fancy, Hilbert spaces form what's called a symmetric monodical category, in which the tensor product is commutative. To be less fancy, there's an the obvious isomorphism $\mathcal{H}_1 \otimes \mathcal{H}_2 \simeq \mathcal{H}_2 \otimes \mathcal{H}_1$ that just swaps the order of the tensor factors. I'm curious as to why you think there should be a difference between the two orderings.

Comment: @d_b It's true that there's a natural isomorphism, but that's not the same thing as equality. The tensor product is not commutative.

Comment: @tparker, I agree that if you fix the Hilbert spaces in each slot of the tensor product, the tensor product between *states* is not commutative. What I'm talking about, and what I assume the OP is asking about, is changing the order in which you take the tensor product *between Hilbert space*. Under $\mathcal{H}_1 \otimes \mathcal{H}_2 \simeq \mathcal{H}_2 \otimes \mathcal{H}_1$, $\left| \psi \right>_1 \otimes \left| \phi \right>_2$ is exactly the same state as $\left| \phi\right>_2 \otimes \left| \psi \right>_1$

Comment: After this discussion, I guess it is fair to say that the question is ambigous and requires more context.  Dear OP, could you clarify the context?

Comment: Another part of the context is whether this maybe is about indistinguishable particles - completely different story altogether again!

Comment: In my question we assume distinguishable subsystems. Pls everyone give some references as you make your point...this is useful discussion. As for monoidal product in v spaces vs general product monoidal category, I am sorry but I can't elaborate further cause I don't understand the terms from cate3gory theory.

Comment: @jmstf94 Please edit your question accordingly, rather than just commenting. Also, please give references to where in Cohen-Tannoudji you find this. Finally, don't expect people to put more work in their answer than you put in your quetions (cf. "please give some references"!)

Answer (score 0):

You can have two different situations.

1. They are distinguishable particles and properly described in different Hilbert spaces $|\psi\rangle \in \mathcal H_1$, $|\chi\rangle \in \mathcal H_2$, in which case it doesn't really matter which order you write them as there is no possibility of confusion (if you change the order of the particles, then you are implicitly changing the order of the Hilbert spaces and it is a matter of no concern)
2. They are indistinguishable particles and changing the order does not affect the physical state. In this case the physical states are described by symmetrised or antisymmetrised states. An overall factor of a constant (in this case $-1$ for antisymmetrised states) also does not alter the physical state. As these are the only states we have to consider, the order does not matter).

Comment: Why the change of the Hilbert Spaces have no implications? Physical or mathematical?

Comment: It cannot affect any calculated results. Since the particles are distinguishable, there is no reason to specify which order they are written in. "An electron and a proton" is no different from "a proton and an electron"

Comment: ok, sure...is there a reference with an elaborate discussion on this subject or is it dismissed as trivial? I mean since you say that it cannot affect any calculated results I would assume that a proof should be a thing, mentioned and needed.

Comment: It is obvious to me that it is trivial, and I think it would be for anyone who worked with the formalism for even a small amount of time. What can be more trivial that saying that "an electron and a proton" is no different from "a proton and an electron"? A little more time is spent on showing the maths of identical particles, which requires symmetrisation and antisymmetrisation, but then the order explicitly does not matter.

Comment: @CharlesFrancis Isn't the indistinguishable case just like saying that "an electron and an electron" is no different from "an electron and an electron"?

Comment: ye you might be right...

Comment: @NorbertSchuch, yes it is like saying that. Which is why we must (anti-)symmetrise. If we did not antisymmetrise an electron and and electron would not be the same as an electron and an electron, because the ordering of the product would give different states, just as observed in the question.